# #3503 Error Attempting to Publish Custom Action via JSSDK

Tags: json, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am attempting to work out what is needed to publish a custom open graph action that includes [user generated photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/). I have made it through the approval process and am currently testing using the JSSDK. I have the following code which seems to work:

```
FB.api('/me/cheezburger-app:create', 'post', {
    meme:'http://cheezburger.com/6459677184'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

My understanding is, to publish this as user generated photo all I need to do is include an image property containing an array of objects like this:

```
FB.api('/me/cheezburger-app:create', 'post', {
    meme:'http://cheezburger.com/6509097984',
    image:[{user_generated:true, url:'https://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/12/8/13/c9Smb0ba2EGTLepkCgEp2g2.jpg'}]
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Sadly, this returns the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#3503) \"[{\"user_generated\":true,\"url\":\"https://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/12/8/13/c9Smb0ba2EGTLepkCgEp2g2.jpg\"}]\" is an invalid value for property \"image:url\" with type \"URL\"","type":"OAuthException","code":3503}}
```

I was able to successfully get the action to publish using the graph api explorer, but it is not using a javascript object and jquery. I assume I am doing something wrong with the way I am passing the extra parameter. But I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven’t tried this yet, but my guess (since it’s not clearly described in the docs) would be that you have to give a *string value* containing JSON-encoded data like in other similar cases.

```
image: '[{"user_generated":"true","url":"https:\/\/i.chzbgr.com\/completestore\/12\/8\/13\/c9Smb0ba2EGTLepkCgEp2g2.jpg"}]'
```

Comment: That still didn't work for me... was there anything else involved?